# Why does Bootstrap put my icon in a different line than the text?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, font-awesome

I created a grid with Bootstrap but when I try to add an icon to my column it appears underneath the text.
Where is the error?

I tried using spans, css inline, css vertical-align.
I also increased the col width, and offset of the following col.

[The icon appears underneath the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmssP.png)

```
<div class="container border bg-light">
    <div class="container pt-2">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-1"><img src="profile.jpg" class="rounded-circle post-img "></div>
            <div class="col-2 col-md-1 col-sm-2 offset-sm-0 offset-1 ml-3 mt-2"><span class="font-weight-bold">Luke_KS
                </span><i class="verify fa fa-check-circle"></i></div>

            <div class="col-2 col-md-1 col-sm-2 mt-2 offset-1 offset-sm-0">
                <p class="font-weight-ligh ml-2">21.12.2020</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-11 offset-1 mt-n1">
                <hr>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-9 offset-sm-1 offset-0 ml-sm-2">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut
                    labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
                    et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Icon wraps to a new line because there is not enough space in the column.

[image]

Try to change `col-2` `col-md-1` `col-sm-2` to classes with more width.

Or you can add css positioning for icon.

```
position: absolute;
top: 4px;
left: -2px;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
 <div class="container border bg-light">
            <div class="container pt-2">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-1"><img src="profile.jpg" class="rounded-circle post-img " /></div>
                    <div class="col-2 offset-sm-0 offset-1 mt-2"><span class="font-weight-bold">Luke_KS
                     <i class="verify fa fa-check-circle ml-2"></i> </span></div>

                    <div class="col-2 col-md-1 col-sm-2 mt-2 offset-1 offset-sm-0">
                        <p class="font-weight-ligh ml-2">21.12.2020</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row ">
                    <div class="col-11 offset-1 mt-n1">
                        <hr />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-9 offset-sm-1 offset-0 ml-sm-2">
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut
                            labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
                            et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                    </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```